# Unable to import sikuli library in RIDE

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, sikuli

I have to write automation scripts using python and Robot framework. I have installed python, Robotframework, RIDE, wxpython. I have installed sikuli library but when I import it in my project, library is not imported. I have tried 'Import Library Spec XML'. My question is from where do I import this .xml or how do I create it?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to declare the Pythonpath on RIDE preferences (Tools>Preferences>Importing), you must add there your libraries location, it helped me with suds library.

I have added there:

> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries

(This could be little different for you if you have installed your python at different location)

Edit:

This could be an issue on the way you are trying to import your library, or you need to download a specific sikuli library that work with robot.

Please check then if you are loading your library like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library            SikuliLibrary
```

got it from: https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check if you are loading your library like that.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether Sikuli is installed in python directory's \Lib\site-packages.
Robot test should contain as below:

*** Settings ***

Documentation     Sikuli Library Demo

Library           SikuliLibrary    mode=NEW

*** Test Cases ***

Sample_Sikuli_Test

blabh blabh etc